# Terraform - How to use tfvars with modules

Tags: terraform

With three different environments, I want to be able to dynamically set variables based on the environment. In my example below, let's say the instance type is different between dev and prod. I'm not able to reference `instance_type` within the module UNLESS I have a `vars.tf` file alongside my `terraform.tfvars`.

The error I get is:

`unknown variable referenced: 'instance_type'. define it with 'variable' blocks`

If that's the case, then wouldn't this file be the same exact file under `modules/apollo/vars.tf`?

I thought `modules/apollo/vars.tf` defines the necessary variables needed for the module. I didn't think it was necessary within the "root" level under `env-dev/services/apollo/`. If there's a "better" way of doing this, I'm all ears.

```
├── env-dev
│   └── services
│       └── apollo
│           ├── main.tf
│           ├── terraform.tfvars    
│           └── vars.tf # Do i need this?
├── env-test
├── global
├── mgmt
└── modules
    ├── apollo
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── user_data.tpl
    │   └── vars.tf
    └── defaults
        └── main.tf
```

## env-dev/services/apollo/terraform.tfvars

```
instance_type    = "t2.medium"
```

## env-prod/services/apollo/terraform.tfvars

```
instance_type    = "t2.large"
```

## modules/apollo/vars.tf

```
variable "instance_type" {
  description = "EC2 Instance Type"
}
```

## modules/apollo/main.tf

```
resource "aws_instance" "instance" {     
  ...
  instance_type           = "${var.instance_type}"
  ...
}
```

Comment: Not sure about the best practice but I don't use terraform.tfvars file. I will provide values directly inside module block usage. In this case, I will provide module variable values in env-dev/services/apollo/main.tf and remove terraform.tfvars and vars.tf. I will add output.tf for any desired values. For any sensitive values I will use a key vault.

Comment: One of the disadvantage of my usage stated above will be that in case of multiple modules being used in env-dev/services/apollo/main.tf, shared variables values will have to be provided multiple times. Modifying a variable value later will require changes in multiple places. That's where .tfvars will become handy to define variables once and use the values in multiple modules. In case of variable modification, only one place to change.

Answer (score 4):

Adjust the structure, this is my understand for your applications.

```
├── dev
│   └── apollo_terraform.tfvars    
├── test
│   └── apollo_terraform.tfvars
├── global
│   └── apollo_terraform.tfvars
├── mgmt
│   └── apollo_terraform.tfvars
├── main.tf,  vars.tf, output.tf, apollo.tf, default.tf, etc
└── modules
    ├── apollo
    │   ├── main.tf
    │   ├── user_data.tpl
    │   └── vars.tf
    └── defaults
        └── main.tf
```

`apollo.tf` will have source module code to use the share module `apollo`. Same setting for `default.tf`

your plan/apply command should be like this:

```
terraform plan -var-file=${env}/apollo_terraform.tfvars
```

Comment: In this case you would declare your infrastructure configs for all environments in the same files and also would have one state file, which is not ideal?

Answer (score 3):

I've been trying to achieve something similar as intuitively it seems this is how it should work, however I am coming to the conclusion that modules are simply not designed for this use case.
Basically you are assigning values to variables that do not exist in your test/prod, to work around this instead of providing assignments in .tfvars you could try to declare them with default values:
env-dev/services/apollo/variables.tf

```
variable "instance_type" {
 default = "t2.medium"
}
```

env-prod/services/apollo/variables.tf

```
variable "instance_type" {
 default = "t2.large"
}
```

having those declared and assigned with default values still does not automatically link them to the input variables declared in your module, so
additionally in `env-dev/services/apollo/main.tf` and `env-prod/services/apollo/main.tf` you would still need to fill in properties for your module:

```
module "aws_inst" {
 source = "..\\..\\..\\modules\\apollo"
 instance_type = "${var.instance_type}"
}
```

You can quickly see how this defeats the purpose of modules in this scenario.

To elaborate, I think that modules were not designed for defining single resource per module to be able to fill in it's values dynamically, but rather to create "collections" of resources within a module where they can share/reuse same variables.

Note that when you are assigning value to `instance_type` key in *[module call](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/modules.html#calling-a-child-module)*, you are actually passing that value to modules *input variable* which is is then assigned to resource key by the same name.